# Parallel.For synchronization with null objects

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am using `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For` to do some heavyweight processing.

My code is:

```
int count = 10;
List<MyObj> results = new List<MyObj>();

Parallel.For(0, count, (index) =>
{
   MyObj obj = GetMyObjMaybe();

   if (obj != null)
      results.Add(obj);
});

if (results.Contains(null))
{
   //break here, and it does
}

//sometimes contains null objects
return results;
}
```

I wouldn't expect to be getting null in the List, but I am. I must be botching the use of `index` somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `c` in `results.Add(c)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `List<MyObj> results` is *not* thread-safe.

You are seeing nulls because `results` could be invalid in many ways.

Either use a [Thread-safe collection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) or guard every access to `results` yourself with a `lock` statement.

Comment: Thank you, Henk. I thought List<T> would be thread-safe for concurrent adding at least. A simple lock object fixed the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes." -SO. I'll be back :P

Comment: @bufferz - in general, assume collections **might** be safe for concurrent reading but they almost never are safe for concurrent writing or mixed reads/writes.  Then check your assumptions in the docs.